# How safe is it to "Cross Install" Debian?

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer, debian-cd

I have migrated to Debian 10 recently and opted for netinstall.

I have two old computers that I repurposed as backup PC's which I am currently using.

PC Phenom

Phenom X4 9750 - DDR2 2GB - Nvidia 8200

PC Athlon

Athlon II X2 250 - DDR3 2GB - Gigabyte 210 Rev 5.0

I decided to make a Debian 10 installation for my Athlon PC by using my Phenom PC since my Athlon PC had a broken PSU that couldn't supply 12V through Molex/SATA power lines and I just didn't trust my USB 3.0 SATA adapter with a PC with an allready messed up PSU.

So I decided to connect my new HDD to the Phenom PC and install Debian 10 there. I successfully installed Debian 10 with XFCE using nonfree netinst cd but I am curious if it will work. When I used SparkyLinux with the Phenom PC lots of time ago. I kept getting "Couldn't find processor microcode" errors whenever I used apt and I am afraid of the same and similar things happening with this "Cross Installation". I couldn't even connect my new HDD to the Athlon PC since I did the installation and I am far from home and thus couldn't test my installation yet.

So In the end, Does "Cross Installing" Debian 10 make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it’s safe, in your circumstances. The bootloader and kernel installed by Debian aren’t tied to the hardware they’re installed on, other than the general architecture; and both `i386` and `amd64` would work on the two CPUs you’re using. The only thing to bear in mind is that your initramfs should be as generic as possible; so make sure that `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`’s `MODULES` line is `MODULES=most`.